# Matlab - LDA "The pooled covariance matrix of TRAINING must be positive definite."

Tags: matlab, classification, lda

Can someone help me out with this problem. I have trying to figure this out from a long time.

I have a training_Set: `<1530*270400 double>`
and Test_Set: `<4794*270400 double>`

I am using Linear discriminant analysis method

```
class = classify(Test_Set,Training_Set,train_label,'linear')
```

Error using classify (line 228)

The pooled covariance matrix of TRAINING must be positive definite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The pooled covariance matrix of TRAINING must be positive definite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937609/the-pooled-covariance-matrix-of-training-must-be-positive-definite)

Answer (score 2):

In order for the covariance matrix of TRAINING to be positive definite, you must at the very least have more observations than variables in `Test_Set`. In your case, it seems as though you have many more variables (270400) than observations (1530). You can try dimension reduction before classifying.

I have answered a very similar question here: [Matlab bug with linear discriminant analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923726/matlab-bug-with-linear-discriminant-analysis/16057976#16057976)