# Matlab - clasify error

Tags: matlab, classification

I am trying to classify a vector with a specified group of vectors (A-K) as the traing set, but this error keeps apeearing :

**"Error using classify (line 277)
The covariance matrix of each group in TRAINING must be positive definite."**

I have used all the available types of discriminant function. 
What can I do?

My code is:

```
vector = [eccentricity HU_moments] 
A = [1.307582846151761 0.002328240818267 0.000000339787418 0.000000000010006 0.000000000013205 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000007 0.000000000000000];
B = [0.852509811942313 0.001274564902091 0.000000019429171 0.000000000000943 0.000000000001518 -0.000000000000000 0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000000];
C = [1.807216375229099 0.001395498724663 0.000000396375718 0.000000000000350 0.000000000000259 -0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000000];
D = [0.509130473161456 0.001982641576184 0.000001125118768 0.000000000001974 0.000000000001711 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000001 0.000000000000000];

E = [1.313285591628449 0.000905989501632 0.000000073375232 0.000000000000303 0.000000000000468 0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000000 0.000000000000000];
F = [1.281052301091977 0.001198833109321 0.000000131250645 0.000000000000905 0.000000000004111 0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000001 0.000000000000000];
G = [1.335248144516864 0.000971636567473 0.000000083156649 0.000000000000682 0.000000000000454 -0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000000 0.000000000000000];
H = [1.376252536144123 0.000965808457692 0.000000072135656 0.000000000000019 0.000000000002546 0.000000000000000 -0.000000000000001 0.000000000000000];
I = [1.349440659700456 0.001293050578171 0.000000087781986 0.000000000001836 0.000000000013089 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000003 0.000000000000000];
J = [0.756966055091135 0.000933970841629 0.000000001067259 0.000000000000639 0.000000000005506 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000000];
K = [1.310488452377568 0.001299510364774 0.000000136489347 0.000000000003186 0.000000000002315 0.000000000000000 0.000000000000001 -0.000000000000000];

%Normalize based on the standard deviation
A=A/std(A);
B=B/std(B);
C=C/std(C);
D=D/std(D);
E=E/std(E);
F=F/std(F);
G=G/std(G);
H=H/std(H);
I=I/std(I);
J=J/std(J);
K=K/std(K);
vector=vector/std(vector);

classify(vector,[A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K],[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'quadratic')
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937609/the-pooled-covariance-matrix-of-training-must-be-positive-definite) which is for a similar problem.  The suggested solution there was to increase the size of the training set.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that already but I cant increase it. Its the size of the dataset is standard. Can I work around the error some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really meant to have those "-0.000000000000000" entries? Just wondering if some error has crept into earlier calculations of your training set.

At any rate, as the last few variables in each training set are close to zero in all cases, they might not be very useful in classification anyway.  If you take, for example, only the first four values of A through D, the resulting covariance matrix you form from them *is* positive definite (with or without normalisation). You could try just classifying using those four columns (or maybe the first five) and see if it gives you sufficient results.  You can test it as such:

```
n = 4;
Q = [A(1:n); B(1:n); C(1:n); D(1:n)];
Q2 = cov(Q);
chol(Q2); % will error if not positive definite
```

If you need to build in a programmatic check for positive definiteness, use additional outputs (Mathworks recommends using `chol` over `eig` for this):

```
[R,p] = chol(Q2);
```

This will not return an error, but if p is larger than zero, the matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: Thats it! I have eliminated the columns with the zero values and its working fine!!! Thanks a lot!